# How to write a List into CSV file as multiple columns (repeat column for each value of the list)

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

In my autotest, I have a collection of Strings and I need to insert all values into a CSV file into different columns with the same name.

E.g. I have:

```
String name;
List<String> roles;
```

So in a result, I should get a CSV file with:

```
|name|roles|roles|roles|
|Anna|CVV  |CDD  |CVD  |
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've checked existing OpenCSV annotations, but cannot find anything useful there. Annotations that I saw will transform a list/array into a string and write it as one column (CsvBindAndSplitByName/CsvCustomBindByName).
I will try to write a custom mapping strategy or whatever there is needed if I there are no other options.

Answer (score 0):

Use "@CsvBindAndSplitByName". It will split values of the list

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).